# How to create a collection of multi dimensional arrays and not overwrite original values when new ones are pushed

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is my site
http://69.231.195.173:8888/iadprint/products?product=flyers

When the user selects a few selections that relate to the flyer product and presses add to cart. this is what code is executed.

```
if(isset($_POST['btnAddToCart']) && isset($_GET['product']))
    {
        $product_id = $action->getProductID($_GET['product']);

        $attribute[$product_id] = array();


        foreach ($_POST as $field=>$hash) 
        {
            $hash = $security->clean_numeric($hash);

            if($field != "btnAddToCart" && $field != 'price' && !empty($hash))
            {
                array_push($attribute[$product_id], $hash);

            }
        } 

        $_SESSION['iadprint_cart'] = $attribute;
}
```

the array that gets formed looks like this

```
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
            [1] => 36
        )
)
```

inside that main array the 10 refers to flyer product id name. inside of that the 30 and 36 are the ids of the selections.

the problem i'm having is if you select business card and make your selections and add to cart instead of pushing in a format like the picture that is everything inside the array()  for the new product. the data gets overridden. I am using array_push and it should work but it is not.

Comment: i think the problem is here $attribute[$product_id] = array(); where it resets the array and adds the new data. but dont know how else i would write it.

Comment: not it's not that the problem. Also there are a lot of confusing parts here. When the data is overwritten?

Comment: Also what are you using to update the price counter? Ajax os simple Javascript? And it seems oblivious to me that if you click on Add to Cart everything is reset... What's the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

If you want to append array elements from the second array to the first array while not overwriting the elements from the first array and not re-indexing, use the **+ array union operator**:

```
$a = array(10 => array(25,26));
$b = array(22 => array(45,66));
$c = $a + $b;
print_r($c);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
            [1] => 26
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
            [1] => 66
        )
)
```

The keys are preserved in this case.

> Same answer from the other question
>   you posted relating this issue:
>   [merging a multi-dimensional array into another multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212924/merging-a-multi-dimensional-array-into-another-multi-dimensional-array/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be useful **[in_array().](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)**

Comment: well the thing is i cant push in a new array so say i want to push [11] => array([0] => 11, [1] => 12) it should work but it doesnt. and 11 doesnt exist in there. so if i were to add what i mentioned it would over write it even though it doesnt exist.

Comment: You can use this function but its not the correct way of doing it. $result = array_unique($hash);

Comment: sorry i dont get what your saying. i would that push in new values. i'll use in_array() once i have the ability to push in new arrays then i'll check and see before adding duplicates