# merging a multi-dimensional array into another multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

this relates to my previous post.
[how to create a collection of multi dimensional arrays and not overwrite origional values when new ones are pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209265/how-to-create-a-collection-of-multi-dimensional-arrays-and-not-overwrite-origiona)

i am thinking my problem has to do with how i am creating the array. what i'm trying to do is make an array that looks like this

```
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
           [0] => 29
           [1] => 36
        )

)
```

into something like this

```
    Array
    (
        [10] => Array
            (
               [0] => 29
               [1] => 36
            )


 [20] => Array
            (
               [0] => 29
               [1] => 36
            )


 [25] => Array
            (
               [0] => 29
               [1] => 36
            )

    )
```

the 10, 20, and 25 is the product id where the numbers within those are the selections that were selected on that page (in the link i gave above). so each product would have its own collection selected.

when i use array_push instead of doing what i want it to do the first collection of array as in the first example keep reseting. so if i do my selections on say flyers and add to cart then i go to business cards and do my selections and add to cart the array resets and it becomes like the first example. whatever i try i cant get it to merge below a collection like the second example that i have. i have tried array_merge(),array_push but those dont really work.

Comment: If you were to var_dump the array prior to trying to do the insertion, what displays?  I have a feeling you're submitting multiple pages but not carrying the array over from page to page (for example, by setting the array to session).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:-

If you want to append array elements from the second array to the first array while not overwriting the elements from the first array and not re-indexing, use the **+ array union operator**:

```
$a = array(10 => array(25,26));
$b = array(22 => array(45,66));
$c = $a + $b;
print_r($c);
```

**Output**:-

```
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
            [1] => 26
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
            [1] => 66
        )
)
```

Hope this helps.